# Casting float to int in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

```
int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
    int num = m+n-2;
    int den=1;
    double ans = 1;
    while(den<=m-1) {
        ans = ans*(num--)/(den++);
    }
    cout<<ans;
    return (int)ans; 
}
```

The expected answer for m=53, n=4 as  input to the above piece of code is 26235 but the code returns 26234. However, the stdout shows 26235.

Could you please help me understand this behavior?

Comment: What do you think casting a `float` (actually, a `double`) to an `int` is supposed to do?

Comment: Find out the *exact* value of `ans` (hint: print `ans-26235`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to floating-point rounding, your code computes `ans` to be 26,234.999999999985448084771633148193359375. When it is printed with `cout<<ans`, the default formatting does not show the full value and rounds it to “26235”. However, when the actual value is converted to `int`, the result is 26,234.

After setting `num` to `m+n-2`, your code is computing `num`! / ((`m-1`)!(`num-m+1`)!), which of course equals `num`! / ((`num-m+1`)!(`m-1`)!). Thus, you can use either `m-1` or `num-m+1` as the limit. So you can change the `while` line to these two lines:

```
    int limit = m-1 < num-m+1 ? m-1 : num-m+1;
    while(den<=limit) {
```

and then your code will run to the lower limit, which will avoid dividing `ans` by factors that are not yet in it. All results will be exact integer results, with no rounding errors, unless you try to calculate a result that exceeds the range of your `double` format where it is able to represent all integers (up to 2<sup>53</sup> in the ubiquitous IEEE-754 binary64 format used for `double`).